# SQL Table Updates but page does not refresh

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I this script to update/change my SQL table. When I submit the data the table reflects the changes but I have to reload the page manually to see the changes reflected on my page.

```
    if (isset($_POST['mandar'])) {
        $sql_man="INSERT INTO busca (producto, username) VALUES ('$_POST[producto]','$_POST[usuario]')";
        $mysqli->query($sql_man);   
         echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=/protected_page.php'>";

} else if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $total = count($_POST['cantidad_pedido']); 
      $user_id_arr = $_POST['id']; 
      $rank_arr = $_POST['cantidad_pedido'];
      $rank_pedido = $_POST['p_objetivo'];
      for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
           { 
         $id = $user_id_arr[$i];
         $rank = $rank_arr[$i]; 
         $rank_p = $rank_pedido[$i];

         $query = "UPDATE busca SET `cantidad_pedido`= '".$rank."', `p_objetivo`= '".$rank_p."' WHERE `id`= '".$id."'";
         $valor = "UPDATE `busca` SET `ctot_obj` = `p_objetivo`*`cantidad_pedido`WHERE `id`= '".$id."'";
         $mysqli->query($query);
         $mysqli->query($valor);
        } 

   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=/protected_page.php'>";            
                                        }
```

Comment: `if($valor)` if what? `$valor` is just a string

Comment: have you tried header location, instead of the html meta?

Comment: Yes. Same Result. Table updated but page does not refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Moved the POST statements to a separate page and redirected from there!